# What fonts are available to the console log

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

A short while ago I discovered using %c in a JS console log - this allows you to style the console log.

---

for instance:

```
console.log("%cWelcome to the jungle!", "color: teal; font-size: 30px; background: #fff; font-weight: bold")
```

Outputs:

[image]

---

If your like me this will make you geek the F out and think of millions of useless applications!

But I'm stuck on one thing (and the docs have not helped me here).

DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

**What fonts can and cannot be used in a console log using %c to style the output?**

By that I mean, I can use Arial in the console log but not my custom fonts? See below:

Can you use custom fonts i.e. if you have a custom font on your domain, have decaled it via font-face, can that you then call it to be used here? (I have not managed to get this working as of yet so need some direction here if it is possible).

Thanks in advance -
W

Comment: what fonts do you have in your operating system?

Comment: Wouldn't the fonts depend on what you have on your system? It's all local, after all. If you don't have Arial (for whatever reason), I'm not sure how it'd work. And if you have some fancy font "Times New Byzantium" you'd be able to use it. Not sure how you can get a canonical list of all possible fonts in this case.

Comment: by the way, I can confirm that not ALL fonts do work - no pattern to it though - prebundled (in windows) or added on, some work some don't

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - So your leaning towards it depending on what fonts you have on your local system....? Its a bit strange based on your comments - afterall the console log has access to the data of the site that is loaded - I would have assumed that this also includes its fonts (but not the case from me playing around). - Maybe this is just another overlooked minor feature of the web?